# How to use Barcode Rendering Framework Codeplex?

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a problem with Barcode Rendering from Codeplex, I never use that Framework. Can anyone teach me how to use that Framework for print *Code 128* Barcode?

Please let me know if someone can do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/sfbarcode/barcode/barcode

try this dude. they are rendering correctly it seems

Comment: Is that uses Barcode Rendering from Codeplex? Because I must use that Framework. Anyway, thank you for your answer mister.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a howto and external resource

Comment: @Amirul.. nope they use their own rendering engine, not codeplex

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj. thank you for your help. But, I must use the rendering framework from Codeplex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no answer yet. I made a Code 39 implementation like this. (barcode variable is a string i get from my function)

```
int maxheight = 40;
Code39BarcodeDraw barcode39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum;   
Image img = barcode39.Draw(barcode, maxheight);
```

Code 128 should look like this

```
int maxheight = 40;
Code128BarcodeDraw barcode128 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
Image img = barcode128.Draw("TESTBARCODE", maxheight);
```

Im using `Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework` version `3.1.10729.1` downloaded from NuGet

Answer (score 0):

Try [ZXing.NET](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) project capable of generating barcodes, hosted on the Codeplex.